# Bug with parents when changing document owner

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a problem using drive. The result is the same in both drive sdk and drive web. I have a folder (1) shared with a user (X). The (X) user creates a new folder(2) into folder(1) and changes the folder(2) owner to me.

After, in my drive, folder(2) is in folder(1) and in my drive (root). The parent should be only in the folder(2).

This appears to be a bug...

Comment: If the API works like the UI, it is not a bug in the API, sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks!! but this behavior is ok?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not a bug.

Consider the same in network share the folder that have shared inside the parent shared folder has been separately shown on the shared network. Likewise the folder that u have shared second has been shown separately as well as on the parent folder.

If the parent id defers it will be a bug.

But in this case both have same parent id. So it wont be a bug.